# Why are projectionless $C^*$-algebras important (Kadison's conjecture)

Tags: gr.group-theory, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, kk-theory

It was considered an important result for a long time to show that the reduced $C^*$-algebra of the free group $C^*_r(F_2)$ has no nontrivial projections. I believe this is also known as Kadison's conjecture. It was initially proved by [Pimsner and Voiculescu](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24713853) and subsequently, [Cuntz](https://eudml.org/doc/152568) gave an alternative proof using KK-theory. The question is rather silly and a bit historical but, why is this result considered so important?

For example, if we take another famous example from K-theory, namely Elliott's classification result of AF-algebras using $K_0$ group it is quite self-evident why this is deemed a result of paramount importance, namely we gained a classification of a large class of $C^*$-algebras.

My question is then how come, such a specific group, namely $F_2$ was chosen and why is it so important that $C_r^*(F_2)$ is projectionless (apart from the trivial projections)?
It seems to have generated a lot of results and the development and motivation for a lot of new very nice theory, but the question itself seems quite specific, I mean we are talking about one specific $C^*$-algebra in the end.

Thus, does this conjecture have some far-reaching consequences that I'm unaware of, was it important for some historical reason, or something else?
Any and all references are welcome (I'm probably not aware of many things going on in modern mathematics).

Nota bene: I suspect the reason why $F_2$ is so specific is that it is, to my knowledge, one of the best-known paradoxical (non-amenable) groups, but I'm not sure I see what is the connection with projections of $C_r^*(F_2)$ (I know that then $C^*(F_2)$ is not nuclear, but again I don't see a clear connection to Kadison's conjecture).

Comment: I’m no expert but I believe the Kadison (aka) Kadison-Kaplansky conjecture states there are no nontrivial projections in the reduced C*-algebra of any torsion-free group.  Kaplansky had already conjectured the are no non-trivial idempotents  for group algebras over  fields. So this is about more than free groups.  Of course free groups are important examples.  The result has been extended to torsion- Hyperbolic groups.   It is also I believe connected with other big conjectures like Baum-Connes and Farrell-Jones.   I’m sure experts can say more.

Comment: Maybe look here https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~dan/KtheoryHandbook-for-authors-only/Lueck-Reich/bcsfinal.pdf

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg 's first comment is correct. Another post hoc motivation for the Kadison-Kaplansky conjecture is that in the setting of discrete abelian groups, being torsion-free is the same as the dual group being connected, and so non-existence of projections can be seen as a consequence of topological structure in the dual. So if one believes in the philosophy of "noncommutative topology" then one might hope that a discrete group being torsion-free is equivalent to the "dual quantum group being connected"

Comment: I think that one reason F_2 was seen as some kind of test case is that its reduced group Cstar algebra was seen at the time as being a rather mysterious object. Compare this with the integer Heisenberg group H_3, which is also torsion-free and non-abelian. The Cstar algebra of H_3 can be analyzed using the structure of H_3, in particular it can be expressed as a bundle over the circle whose fibres are other well-known Cstar algebras (rotation algebras, if I recall correctly) and so one can try to understand it by analyzing what happens in each fibre. No such tool exists for C_r^\ast(F_2)

Comment: According to Powers abstract of his 1975 Duke paper: "At a conference held in Baton Rouge in 1967 J. Dixmier posed
the question of whether every simple C*-algebra is generated by its projections.
A couple of years later R. Kadison suggested to us that the C*-algebra associated
with the left regular representation of the free group on two generators should
provide an example of a simple C*-algebra without projections. In this paper
we show that this algebra is simple, i.e., it has no non trivial two-sided ideals.
We still do not know if this algebra contains projections."